# Adjust container div position if header hides

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, transform

I want to hide the header smoothly when scroll happens in container div. So, I used `translateY` instead of `margin-top` & `top` for better smoothness and performance.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyzj5uar/9/)**

In this above link you can check. When you scroll green background div, header will hide smoothly. But, I want to adjust the **.ccc & .ddd** div also to top position.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyzj5uar/13/) - This is What I want But without using translateY to .css & .ddd**

In this above link I achieved what I want. But, I want to achieve without using any `transform` properties to **.ccc & .ddd** classes. In second link I have added some hardcode `transform: translateY(-35px)` to .css & .ddd classes.

Is there any other option to adjust the remaining container div & footer div without using `translateY` to .css & .ddd classes?

Answer (score 1):

I use height transition. Is it ok for you?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".ccc").bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {        
                      if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
                  $(".bbb").removeClass("bbbAfter");
                } else {
                  $(".bbb").addClass("bbbAfter");
                }         
        });
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.aaa {
background: #ccc;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh
}
.bbb {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  transition: .3s height;
}
.bbbAfter {
  /*transform: translateY(-100%)*/
  height:0;
}
.ccc {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height:300px;
  overflow-y:auto
}
.ddd {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aaa">
<div class="bbb">

</div>
<div class="ccc">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div class="ddd">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: NOOOOO... I don't want to use height, top, margin-top. I want to hide header using transform property only..

Comment: its ok. Thansk for trying.. :-)

Comment: Can I use an extra div and move this new content up and down?

Comment: Yes. You can add extra div.

Comment: Its good. But, You should not hardcoded like this **.bbbAfter { transform: translateY(-35px) }**. It should be like this translateY(-100%). In your code I have tried -100% its not working as I expected.

Comment: Because, In my case header is dynamic. It will vary according to title characters length. So, I have avoided pixels and using -100%.